# aria-expanded="false" does not work on load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I copied this example to my page but wanted to make all accordion to be closed to begin with

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

So I set all the aria-expanded to false. Like in this fiddle

```
aria-expanded="false"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0sjhnzdy/1/

Also the aria-multiselectable="false" seems to be ignored. When I change this nothing happens